# How much should one elaborate?

Tags: discussion

I view this site as having a primary respondent that is the OP of a question. Thus, I try to limit myself to the question asked and not go into details about related things that may have to do with the original question indirectly. I was asked to elaborate on something that appeared to me to be off topic from the original question, although it was related. Should I have elaborated? Is this off topic? More generally, if something is not asked in the original question, should it be answered? If so, when?

Here is the link to the posted answer: [Bandwidth vs. sampling rate of DAC](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41025/bandwidth-vs-sampling-rate-of-dac/41026#41026)

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's hard, because sometimes the OP doesn't understand enough to know what they don't understand... so you need to take a "shotgun" or "scattergun" approach to answering.

I'd say elaborate as much as you have time for, or as much as you want.  If you've already answered the question, then leave it.  I tend to favor being more forthcoming if the OP asks follow-up questions... but sometimes it tries my patience. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @PeterK. I'll add that answering questions is for me as well a way to order my thoughts, or to elaborate one a novel topic. So elaborate as much as you feel for the OP, or/and as much as you can afford to clarify your mind (and others), providing additional food for thought.